# Chrome SVG fill not working

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

I'm having a problem with getting a fill value in CSS to work in Chrome with an SVG icon. Firefox and other browsers render the fill fine but in Chrome what should be the fill is straight black.

This is the css

```css
.color-primary .session { background: #4e60ab; fill: #a4add8; }
```

It seems pretty straightforward and again, renders ok in Firefox. Any one else experience something like this?

Comment: Can you show the markup you're using?

Comment: Check the path and if your chrome is under 41 it's a bug .

Comment: Add some information about how you are referencing your icon.  For example, is it inline, or via an external icon file?